# Substring all aria-label elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, swiper.js

HTML

```
<div role="group" class="swiper-slide w-dyn-item" aria-label="1 / 13" 
<div role="group" class="swiper-slide w-dyn-item" aria-label="2 / 13" 
<div role="group" class="swiper-slide w-dyn-item swiper-slide-prev" aria-label="3 / 13" 
<div role="group" class="swiper-slide w-dyn-item swiper-slide-active" aria-label="4 / 13" 
<div role="group" class="swiper-slide w-dyn-item swiper-slide-next" aria-label="5 / 13" 
<div role="group" class="swiper-slide w-dyn-item" aria-label="6 / 13"
```

Here I have a JS script working to get the number of the active slide in result of a variable. to get it, I've substring info from "aria-label" (keeping only slide number before " / 13") of the active slide:

```
   var activeslide = $('.swiper-slide-active').attr('aria-label');
    activeslide = activeslide.substring(0, activeslide.indexOf(" "))  
    var numactiveslide = parseInt(activeslide);
    numactiveslide = numactiveslide - 1;
    players[(numactiveslide)].play();
```

**result** // numactiveslide: "4"

****How to get the same for not 1 but 3 special slides (prev,active,next).**
I try to get the same, working for a new array of 3 actives slides (swiper-slide-prev, swiper-slide-active and swiper-slide-next).

**This is the var of the selected slides:**

```
 var **activeslides** = $('.swiper-slide-prev,.swiper-slide-active,.swiper-slide-next');
```

**Expected result is the 3 actives slides numbers:**
// numactiveslides = 3,4,5

How to get a code working by writing a **loop** or **forEach** or this kind of thing? This should be easy but I didn't manage to repeat the substring for each element, to get at the end an array of :

```
numactivesslides (3):
        numactivesslides[0] = 3
        numactivesslides[1] = 4
        numactivesslides[2] = 5
```

Comment: Very hard to understand your Q .

Comment: if you watch the html part, I tried to get 3 numbers in an array, each one you can find in aria label without "/13" of each special "actives" slides (classnamed swiper-slide-prev, swiper-slide-active, and swiper-slide-next) - so in this example, I ask the code to get "3,4,5" in a variable array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've finally found the answer. It works fine.

```
    var activeslides;
    var activslidesnumber = [];
    var activplyrs = [];
    var activslidlength;
    
    setTimeout(function(){
    activeslides = $('.swiper-slide-prev,.swiper-slide-active,.swiper-slide-next');
    console.log("actives slides:",activeslides);
    activslidlength = activeslides.length;
    console.log('activslidlength ',activslidlength);
    var arialabel;
    for (let n = 0; n < activslidlength; n ++) {  
    //get numbers
    arialabel = activeslides[n].getAttribute('aria-label');
    //update to keep only first num before space
    arialabel = arialabel.substring(0, arialabel.indexOf(" "));
    arialabel = parseInt(arialabel);
    // put each arialabels on this var list
    activslidesnumber.push(arialabel);
    // fit fist slide to first player
    activplyrs.push(arialabel - 1);
    };

console.log("actives slides num:",activslidesnumber);
console.log('activplyrs ',activplyrs)

// THEN IF NEEDED, PLAY PLYR ON ACTIVE SLIDES

    if (activplyrs[2] == undefined) {
    covplayers[(activplyrs[0])].play();
    covplayers[(activplyrs[1])].play();
    } else {
    covplayers[(activplyrs[0])].play();
    covplayers[(activplyrs[1])].play();
    covplayers[(activplyrs[2])].play();

}, 200);
```

//then do all the same for passives slides with covplayers.pause();